# node-gyp fedora 21 build node-libtorrent won t work

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, fedora-21, libtorrent-rasterbar

I'm running fedora 21 OS, with enabled "Development tools and creative suite" module.

```
Linux maboiteaspam 3.17.8-300.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 8 23:32:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've specifically installed rb_libtorrent-devel via yum

```
Paquets installés
Nom                 : rb_libtorrent-devel
Architecture        : x86_64
Version             : 1.0.2
Révision            : 1.fc21
Taille              : 3.8 M
Dépôt               : installed
Depuis le dépôt     : fedora
Résumé              : Development files for rb_libtorrent
URL                 : http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/
Licence             : BSD and zlib and Boost
Description         : The rb_libtorrent-devel package contains libraries and header files for
                    : developing applications that use rb_libtorrent.
                    : 
                    : The various source and header files included in this package are licensed
                    : under the revised BSD, zlib/libpng, and Boost Public licenses. See the various
                    : COPYING files in the included documentation for the full text of these
                    : licenses, as well as the comments blocks in the source code for which license
                    : a given source or header file is released under.
```

I'm running node and node-gyp,

```
maboiteaspam [14:07:20] ~ node -v
v0.10.35
maboiteaspam [14:07:23] ~ node-gyp -v
v1.0.2
```

When i try to install node-libtorrent, which can be found here https://github.com/fanatid/node-libtorrent,

```
npm i fanatid/node-libtorrent
```

I'm facing error messages like:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/maboiteaspam/Bureau/the-public-network/node_modules/node-libtorrent/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libtorrent/src/module.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libtorrent/src/add_torrent_params.o
../src/add_torrent_params.cpp: In function ‘libtorrent::add_torrent_params nodelt::add_torrent_params_from_object(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’:
../src/add_torrent_params.cpp:48:21: erreur: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<char>’ and ‘std::vector<char>*’)
       p.resume_data =& rd;
                     ^
../src/add_torrent_params.cpp:48:21: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/vector:69:0,
                 from /usr/include/libtorrent/add_torrent_params.hpp:37,
                 from ../src/add_torrent_params.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<char>*’ to ‘const std::vector<char>&’
../src/add_torrent_params.cpp:57:25: erreur: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned char>’ and ‘std::vector<unsigned char>*’)
       p.file_priorities =& fp;
                         ^
../src/add_torrent_params.cpp:57:25: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/vector:69:0,
                 from /usr/include/libtorrent/add_torrent_params.hpp:37,
                 from ../src/add_torrent_params.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<unsigned char>*’ to ‘const std::vector<unsigned char>&’
libtorrent.target.mk:100: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/libtorrent/src/add_torrent_params.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libtorrent/src/add_torrent_params.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/maboiteaspam/Bureau/the-public-network/node_modules/node-libtorrent/build'
```

How can I overcome those problems and use rb libtorrent via the node bindings ?

Comment: It's a coding bug. You should file an issue on the project's issue tracker.

Comment: i doubt it as i ve been able to install the very same package on ubuntu@14.thanks anyway.